# A method to resize frame after decoding on client side

Tags: opencv

I've just joined a project to build a realtime video streaming application using ffmpeg/opencv/c++ via udp socket. On server side, they want to transmit a video size (640x480) to client, in order to reduce data transmission through network I resize the video to (320x240) and send frame. On client side (client), after receiving frame, we will upscale the frame back to (640x480). Using H265 for encode/decoding.

As I am just a beginner with video encoding, I would like to understand how to down-sampling & up-sampling the frame at server & client side in which we can incorporate with the video encoder/decoder.

A simple idea came into my mind that after decoding avframe -> Mat frame, I will upsampling this frame then display it.

I am not sure my idea is right or wrong. I would like to seek advice from any people who had experience in this area. Thank you very much!

```
static void updateFrameCallback(AVFrame *avframe, void* userdata) {
    VideoStreamUDPClient* streamer = static_cast<VideoStreamUDPClient*> (userdata);
    TinyClient* client = static_cast<TinyClient*> (streamer->userdata);

    //Update Frame
    pthread_mutex_lock(&client->mtx_updateFrame);
    if (streamer->irect.width == client->frameSize.width
            && streamer->irect.height == client->frameSize.height) {
        cvtAVFrameYUV4202Frame(&avframe, client->frame);
        printf("TinyClient: Received Full Frame\n");
    } else {
        Mat block;
        cvtAVFrameYUV4202Frame(&avframe, block);
        block.copyTo(client->frame(streamer->irect));
    }

    //How to resize frame before display it!!!

    imshow("Frame", client->frame);
    waitKey(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&client->mtx_updateFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want just to resize frame after decoding. In opencv you can do it like this

```
if(...)
{
...
}
else 
{
    Mat block;
    cvtAVFrameYUV4202Frame(&avframe, block);
    Mat temp;
    resize(block, temp, 640,480)
    temp.copyTo(client->frame(streamer->irect));
}

//client->frame will always have 640x480
imshow("Frame" client->frame);
```

I don't have much experience in video decoding but from what I know you cannot resize video( or single frame) without decoding it first.

Comment: Glad that I could help you :)